# What do you call a DIY AC plug?

Tags: electrical

This may the dumbest question ever, but I'm trying to replace the AC plug on a small appliance (it's European but voltage-switchable and I'm using it in the US), and I don't know what to call those replacement plugs (i.e. I can't find one on Amazon). I just need a two-prong US male AC plug that has e.g. screw terminals I can wire to inside the shell. I know I've seen such things, so my search terms must be wrong. Can anyone help?

(N.B. Not looking for a plug adapter. Want to actually replace the one on the cord.)

Comment: Q: What do you call a diy high-voltage plug? `A: A fire hazard`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Why?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -- he's not looking to build a plug from sheet copper, brass screws, and molten plastic, he wants one he can put on the end of a cord himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search for "replacement plug" on Amazon gives me a few hits like this:

- [Leviton 101-P 2 Wire Plug, Light Duty, Polarized, Brown](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPAN84)
- [Coleman Cable 05984 Replacement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPANE8)

Comment: Super. That first link is what I was looking for. Thanks.